# Método filter retorna [object Object]

Tags: javascript, array, filtro

No se muestra el resultado, solo aparece esto en la consola:

> Los estudiantes que aprobaron son: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Ejemplo:

```js
const estudiantes =[
    {nombre:'Angelica', nota: 9.2},
    {nombre:'Felipe', nota: 9.0},
    {nombre:'Katia', nota: 9.4},
    {nombre:'Jose', nota: 8.8},
    {nombre:'Daniel', nota:8.0},
    {nombre:'Alberto', nota: 7.2},
    {nombre:'Fernanda', nota: 7.0},
    {nombre:'Carla', nota:6.4},
    {nombre:'Jesús', nota: 6.8},
    {nombre:'Daniel<', nota:5.0}
];

let aprobado = estudiantes.filter(estudiante => estudiante.nota >= 7.0);
console.log(`Los estudiantes que aprobaron son: ${aprobado}`);
```

Comment: No está claro cuál es la pregunta ni cuál es el resultado que esperas que se imprima en la consola. Indica más detalles.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

El motivo por el que obtienes esa respuesta es porque estás imprimiendo objetos como cadenas y la conversión es a `[object Object]`.

Dentro de tu template literal, puedes utilizar map para devolver un `Array` con los nombres de los estudiantes y generar una cadena de texto usando el método `join` usando como separador `,`.

Aquí te dejo el ejemplo.

```js
const estudiantes =[
    {nombre:'Angelica', nota: 9.2},
    {nombre:'Felipe', nota: 9.0},
    {nombre:'Katia', nota: 9.4},
    {nombre:'Jose', nota: 8.8},
    {nombre:'Daniel', nota:8.0},
    {nombre:'Alberto', nota: 7.2},
    {nombre:'Fernanda', nota: 7.0},
    {nombre:'Carla', nota:6.4},
    {nombre:'Jesús', nota: 6.8},
    {nombre:'Daniel<', nota:5.0}
];

let aprobado = estudiantes.filter(estudiante => estudiante.nota >= 7.0);
console.log(`Los estudiantes que aprobaron son: ${aprobado.map(el => el.nombre).join(', ')}`);
```

Otra opción que tienes, con `reduce` podría ser así:

```js
const estudiantes =[
    {nombre:'Angelica', nota: 9.2},
    {nombre:'Felipe', nota: 9.0},
    {nombre:'Katia', nota: 9.4},
    {nombre:'Jose', nota: 8.8},
    {nombre:'Daniel', nota:8.0},
    {nombre:'Alberto', nota: 7.2},
    {nombre:'Fernanda', nota: 7.0},
    {nombre:'Carla', nota:6.4},
    {nombre:'Jesús', nota: 6.8},
    {nombre:'Daniel<', nota:5.0}
];

let aprobado = estudiantes.filter(estudiante => estudiante.nota >= 7.0);
console.log(`Los estudiantes que aprobaron son: ${aprobado.reduce((prev, curr, i) => {
  if(i === 0) return curr.nombre;
  
  return `${prev}${aprobado.length -1 === i ? ` y` : `,`} ${curr.nombre}`;
}, '')}`);
```

Comment: Si, lo he hecho teniendo en cuenta la lógica mas sencilla. Podría iterar e ir imprimiendo los valores, pero igual eso puede complicar la lógica mientras que usando mapa lo reduces a una línea. Otra opción podría ser con reduce, pero igualmente un elemento nuevo hay que crear.

Answer (score 11):

Obtienes ese resultado por que si imprimes `aprobado`, obtienes algo como esto:

```
console.log(aprobado)
```

Obtienes esto:

```
[[object Object] {
  nombre: "Angelica",
  nota: 9.2
}, [object Object] {
  nombre: "Felipe",
  nota: 9
}, [object Object] {
  nombre: "Katia",
  nota: 9.4
}, [object Object] {
  nombre: "Jose",
  nota: 8.8
}, [object Object] {
  nombre: "Daniel",
  nota: 8
}, [object Object] {
  nombre: "Alberto",
  nota: 7.2
}, [object Object] {
  nombre: "Fernanda",
  nota: 7
}]
```

Dado lo cual necesitas recorrerlo con un bucle, por ejemplo el `foreach()`

Tu código debería quedar así:

```js
    const estudiantes =[
                {nombre:'Angelica', nota: 9.2},
                {nombre:'Felipe', nota: 9.0},
                {nombre:'Katia', nota: 9.4},
                {nombre:'Jose', nota: 8.8},
                {nombre:'Daniel', nota:8.0},
                {nombre:'Alberto', nota: 7.2},
                {nombre:'Fernanda', nota: 7.0},
                {nombre:'Carla', nota:6.4},
                {nombre:'Jesús', nota: 6.8},
                {nombre:'Daniel<', nota:5.0}
            ];
    
            let aprobado = estudiantes.filter(estudiante => estudiante.nota >= 7.0);
            aprobado.forEach((alumno) => {
              console.log(`Los estudiantes aprobados son: ${alumno.nombre}`)
            })
```

Una vez que lo recorres, ya estas en condiciones de acceder a las claves de los distintos objetos contenidos, en este caso la que deseamos obtener es *nombre* entonces lo hacemos con la sintaxis de:

`variable.clave`

*Importante*

> Es importante comprender que al iterar con `filter` tu variable `estudiantes` solo estas aplicando un filtro para obtener una lista depurada de objetos, pero eso no quiere decir que puedes acceder directo a las claves de dichos objetos, entonces por eso se hace necesario un segundo iterador; como en el segundo caso ya no vamos a filtrar data entonces por eso solo nos apoyamos del `forEach`

Answer (score 10):

El problema es la forma como estas imprimiendo en consola, al interpolar la variable usando `${var}` JavaScript esta tomando el valor explicito de la variable e imprimiendola en consola, es decir un "objeto de objetos", tienes 2 posibles soluciones para esto:

1. Enviar la variable a loggear como un parametro adicional:

   console.log('Los estudiantes que aprobaron son:', aprobado);
2. Serializar el contenido de la variable antes de imprimirla

   console.log(`Los estudiantes que aprobaron son: ${JSON.stringify(aprobado)}`);

Seria algo asi:

```js
const estudiantes =[
    {nombre:'Angelica', nota: 9.2},
    {nombre:'Felipe', nota: 9.0},
    {nombre:'Katia', nota: 9.4},
    {nombre:'Jose', nota: 8.8},
    {nombre:'Daniel', nota:8.0},
    {nombre:'Alberto', nota: 7.2},
    {nombre:'Fernanda', nota: 7.0},
    {nombre:'Carla', nota:6.4},
    {nombre:'Jesús', nota: 6.8},
    {nombre:'Daniel<', nota:5.0}
];

let aprobado = estudiantes.filter(estudiante => estudiante.nota >= 7.0);

//usando parametro adicional
console.log('Los estudiantes que aprobaron son: ', aprobado);

//serializando la variable antes de imprimir
console.log(`Los estudiantes que aprobaron son: ${JSON.stringify(aprobado)}`);
```

Answer (score 8):

La funcion `console.log` no imprime array de objetos.  Tienes que iterar el resultado e imprimirlo asi:

```js
const estudiantes =[
            {nombre:'Angelica', nota: 9.2},
            {nombre:'Felipe', nota: 9.0},
            {nombre:'Katia', nota: 9.4},
            {nombre:'Jose', nota: 8.8},
            {nombre:'Daniel', nota:8.0},
            {nombre:'Alberto', nota: 7.2},
            {nombre:'Fernanda', nota: 7.0},
            {nombre:'Carla', nota:6.4},
            {nombre:'Jesús', nota: 6.8},
            {nombre:'Daniel<', nota:5.0}
        ];

        let aprobado = estudiantes.filter(estudiante => estudiante.nota >= 7.0);
        console.log(`Los estudiantes que aprobaron son: `);
        aprobado.forEach(function(estudiante) {
          console.log(estudiante.nombre);
        });
```

Comment: La respuesta es correcta, Puede también usar ```console.log('Los estudiantes que aprobaron son: '+JSON.stringfy(aprobado)```  si lo que deseas es solo ver en consola, pero con el  `forEach` tiene la posibilidad de mostrar en la vista con ```{   $(document).prepend('<li>'+estudiante.nombre+'</li>')```

Answer (score 1):

La consola del navegador puede recibir más de un parámetro, considero que la forma más sencilla de hacer lo que quieres es de ésta manera:

`console.log('Los estudiantes que aprobaron son: ', aprobado);`

eso daría el siguiente resultado..

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]